# How to display correct answer in different color than the rest?

Tags: php

I am working on a quiz building application that will let a user enter a quiz question with four possible answers. They must select which answer will be correct with a radio button. I then need to display the answers in a random order with the correct one being a different color than the rest. Currently I able to display the answers in a random order, but I don't know how to make the answer that was selected with a radio button a different color. Here is what it looks like...

[image]

And this is the result page...

[image]

As you can see, the results are displayed in random order, which is what I want. How can I change the color of "Albany" on the result page to show that it is the correct answer?

Here is my form code....

```
            <form style="text-align:center" action="QuestionReview.php" method="POST">

            <br>
            <label class="instructions" for="question" >Enter your question here</label><br>
            <textarea name="question" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
            <br><br>
            <p class="instructions">
                Please provide four answers to your question and select the 
                correct one.
            </p>
            <input type="radio" name="selection" value="answerA">
                <input type="text" name="answer[]" style="width:400px">
                <br><br>
            <input type="radio" name="selection" value="answerB">
                <input type="text" name="answer[]" style="width:400px">
                <br><br>
            <input type="radio" name="selection" value="answerC">
                <input type="text" name="answer[]" style="width:400px">
                <br><br>
            <input type="radio" name="selection" value="answerD">
                <input type="text" name="answer[]" style="width:400px">
                <br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Entry">
        </form>
```

And here is the result page.....

```
<?php
 // Retrieve the question and answers from the HTML form
 $question = $_POST['question'];
 $answers = $_POST['answer'];
 $selection = $_POST['selection'];
 shuffle($answers);

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Entry Review</title>
    <style>
        .instructions {
            color: #696D6E;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="instructions">Entry Review</h1>
    <p><em>You entered the following question:</em></p>
    <p><strong><?php echo $question; ?></strong></p><br>

    <p><em>These are the answers you provided:</em>
    <p>
        <strong>
            <?php 
                foreach($answers as $value) {
                    echo $value . '<br>';
                }
            ?>
        </strong>
    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could wrap each answer in a `<span>` with a class set to the color you want the text it to be. Then set the color on that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could wrap each answer in `<div>`-s and add style to them only if they were selected.

It is a good idea to change input field names in your form from `selection` and `answer[]` to `answer[selected]` and `answer[body]` respectively. This allows you to group together the body and the correctness indicator of an answer. Now you can modify your `foreach` in the following way:

```
<?php
  foreach($answers as $answer){
    // Print div with style, if this answer is correct
    $answer['selected'] ? print '<div style="color:green;">' : print '<div>';
    echo $answer['body']
    echo '</div>'
  }
?>
```

---

### Form

```
<input type="radio" name="answer[0][selected]" value="true">
    <input type="text" name="answer[0][body]" style="width:400px">
    <br><br>
<input type="radio" name="answer[1][selected]" value="true">
    <input type="text" name="answer[1][body]" style="width:400px">
    <br><br>
<input type="radio" name="answer[2][selected]" value="true">
    <input type="text" name="answer[2][body]" style="width:400px">
    <br><br>
<input type="radio" name="answer[3][selected]" value="true">
    <input type="text" name="answer[3][body]" style="width:400px">
    <br><br>
```

### PHP Code

```
<?php
  // Retrieve the question and answers from the HTML form
  $question = $_POST['question'];
  $answers = $_POST['answer'];

  shuffle($answers);
?>

// . . .

<?php
  foreach($answers as $answer){
    // Print div with style, if this answer is correct
    $answer['selected'] ? print '<div style="color:green;">' : print '<div>';
    echo $answer['body']
    echo '</div>'
  }
?>
```

**P.S**
Make sure to escape the user passed data before you use it!

Comment: I changed the field names and updated the foreach loop, but now nothing displays. Were you able to display the results?

Comment: @MichalPatriak Yes, works perfectly on my side. Check if you made any accidental mistakes

Comment: @MichalPatriak I have added more info to the answer, hope that helps

Comment: no, just `$answers = $_POST['answer'];`. `var_dump($_POST)` to better understand what's happening.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this isn't working for me. My output shows the letter t in green followed by the first letter of the correct answer in green on the next line when I use this code.

Comment: @MichalPatriak Sorry, I had an error in my answer. I've updated it. The names should be `answer[0][body]` etc. Check the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can change your input fields as below:

```
        <input type="radio" name="selection" value="answer0">
            <input type="text" name="answer[]" style="width:400px">
            <br><br>
        <input type="radio" name="selection" value="answer1">
            <input type="text" name="answer[]" style="width:400px">
            <br><br>
        <input type="radio" name="selection" value="answer2">
            <input type="text" name="answer[]" style="width:400px">
            <br><br>
        <input type="radio" name="selection" value="answer3">
            <input type="text" name="answer[]" style="width:400px">
            <br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit Entry">
```

Then you can modify your PHP code(foreach part) as below:

```
<?php 
    foreach($answers as $key=>$value) {
        if($selection == "answer$key"){
            echo "<span style='color:green'>".$value . "</span><br>";
        }else{
            echo $value."<br>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: if($selection == "answer$key"{     <------- Is this correct?

I cannot get anything to display when I change the code.

Comment: A bracket was missing. I have corrected it. Try it now.