# PHP How to print selected answer in green

Tags: php, forms, loops, radio-button, echo

This is similar to a previous question I asked about matching the selected radio button with the value in the input field.

The code lets a user build a quiz by entering a question and 4 possible answers. You must select one of the answers as the correct one and on a separate PHP page, the answers must be displayed with the correct one in green. Originally this problem was solved, but after I modified the code for validation, the original loop for display would not work.

Here is the output of the code:

[image]

I need Albany to print in green since it's the correct answer and was selected with the radio button.

Here is my code for the form:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // Define variables and set to empty values
    $questionErr = $answer0Err = $answer1Err = $answer2Err = $answer3Err = "";
    $question = $answer0 = $answer1 = $answer2 = $answer3 = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $valid = True;

        if (empty($_POST['question'])) {
            $questionErr = "Please supply a question";
            $valid = False;
        } else {
            $question = test_input($_POST['question']);
            $_SESSION['question'] = $_POST['question'];
        }

        if (empty($_POST['answer0'])) {
            $answer0Err = "Please supply a possible answer";
            $valid = False;
        } else {
            $answer0 = test_input($_POST['answer0']);
            $_SESSION['answer0'] = $_POST['answer0'];
        }

        if (empty($_POST['answer1'])) {
            $answer1Err = "Please supply a possible answer";
            $valid = False;
        } else {
            $answer1 = test_input($_POST['answer1']);
            $_SESSION['answer1'] = $_POST['answer1'];
        }

        if (empty($_POST['answer2'])) {
            $answer2Err = "Please supply a possible answer";
            $valid = False;
        } else {
            $answer2 = test_input($_POST['answer2']);
            $_SESSION['answer2'] = $_POST['answer2'];
        }

        if (empty($_POST['answer3'])) {
            $answer3Err = "Please supply a possible answer";
            $valid = False;
        } else {
            $answer3 = test_input($_POST['answer3']);
            $_SESSION['answer3'] = $_POST['answer3'];
        }
    }

    // Function to sanitize data
    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
        return $data;
    }

    // If valid, send to QuestionReview.php to display answers
    if ($valid) {
        $_SESSION['radio'] = $_POST['radio'];
        header('location: QuestionReview.php');
    }
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>User-Created Quiz</title>
        <style>
            .shadow {
                 -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;  /* Safari 3-4, iOS 4.0.2 - 4.2, Android 2.3+ */
                 -moz-box-shadow:    3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;  /* Firefox 3.5 - 3.6 */
                 box-shadow:         3px 3px 5px 6px #ccc;  /* Opera 10.5, IE 9, Firefox 4+, Chrome 6+, iOS 5 */
            }
            .instructions {
                color: #696D6E;
            }
            #form-background {
                background-color: #ECEDE8;
            }
            .error {
                color: red;
            }   
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="width:600px">

        <fieldset id="form-background" class="shadow">
            <h1 class="instructions" style="text-align:center">User-Created Quiz</h1>
            <p class="instructions" style="text-align:center">
            <strong>Please enter a question of your own, 
                    along with 4 possible answers in the 
                    form below. Be sure to select the 
                    correct answer to your question
                    before submitting the form.</strong>
            </p>
            <form style="text-align:center;" method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

                <br>
                <label class="instructions" for="question" >Enter your question here</label><br>
                <input type="text" name="question" size="50" value='<?php echo $question;?>' />
                <span class="error">* <br /><?php echo $questionErr; ?></span>
                <br><br>
                <p class="instructions">
                    Please provide four answers to your question and select the 
                    correct one.
                </p>
                    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="answer0">
                    <input type="text" name="answer0" value="<?php echo $answer0; ?>" style="width:400px">
                    <span class="error">* <br /><?php echo $answer0Err; ?></span>
                    <br><br>

                    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="answer1">
                    <input type="text" name="answer1" value="<?php echo $answer1; ?>" style="width:400px">
                    <span class="error">* <br /><?php echo $answer1Err; ?></span>
                    <br><br>

                    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="answer2">
                    <input type="text" name="answer2" value="<?php echo $answer2; ?>" style="width:400px">
                    <span class="error">* <br /><?php echo $answer2Err; ?></span>
                    <br><br>

                    <input type="radio" name="radio" value="answer3">
                    <input type="text" name="answer3" value="<?php echo $answer3; ?>" style="width:400px">
                    <span class="error">* <br /><?php echo $answer3Err; ?></span>
                    <br><br>

                    <input type="submit" value="Submit Entry">
            </form>
        </fieldset>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my code for the result page:

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // Pull all variables from SESSION
    $question =  $_SESSION['question'];
    $answer0 = $_SESSION['answer0'];
    $answer1 = $_SESSION['answer1'];
    $answer2 = $_SESSION['answer2'];
    $answer3 = $_SESSION['answer3'];
    $radio = $_SESSION['radio'];

    $answerArray = array($answer0, $answer1, $answer2, $answer3);
    shuffle($answerArray);
?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Entry Review</title>
        <style>
            .instructions {
                color: #696D6E;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="instructions">Entry Review</h1>
        <p><em>You entered the following question:</em></p>
        <p><strong><?php echo $question; ?></strong></p><br>



        <p><em>These are the answers you provided:</em>
        <p>
            <strong>
                <?php 

                if(isset($_SESSION['radio'])) {
                    $radio =  $_SESSION['radio'];
                    foreach ($answerArray as $value) {
                        echo $value . "<br />";
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "Please click the back button in your browser and select a correct answer";
                }
                ?>
            </strong>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: "Originally this problem was solved, but after I modified ..." -- Well what was the original content, and which essential code did you remove?

Comment: Why would you mind making a loop if you can just copy/paste around?

Comment: This was my original question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36826587/how-to-display-correct-answer-in-different-color-than-the-rest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On **QuestionReview.php** page, get the correct answer like this,

```
$correct_answer = $_SESSION[$_SESSION['radio']];
```

So keep your quiz page as it is and after submitting, process your form like this:

**QuestionReview.php:**

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // Pull all variables from SESSION
    $question =  $_SESSION['question'];
    $answer0 = $_SESSION['answer0'];
    $answer1 = $_SESSION['answer1'];
    $answer2 = $_SESSION['answer2'];
    $answer3 = $_SESSION['answer3'];
    $correct_answer = $_SESSION[$_SESSION['radio']];

    $answerArray = array($answer0, $answer1, $answer2, $answer3);
    shuffle($answerArray);

?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Entry Review</title>
        <style>
            .instructions {
                color: #696D6E;
            }

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1 class="instructions">Entry Review</h1>
        <p><em>You entered the following question:</em></p>
        <p><strong><?php echo $question; ?></strong></p><br>



        <p><em>These are the answers you provided:</em>
        <p>
            <strong>
                <?php 

                if(isset($_SESSION['radio'])) {
                    foreach ($answerArray as $value) {
                        $output = "<span";
                        if($value == $correct_answer){
                            $output .= " class='instructions'";
                        }
                        $output .= ">" . $value . "</span><br />";
                        echo $output;
                    }
                } else {
                    echo "Please click the back button in your browser and select a correct answer";
                }
                ?>
            </strong>
        </p>
    </body>
</html>
```

In each iteration of the `foreach` loop, check if the current option equals to the correct answer or not. If it is then apply the class `instructions` to the current option.

**Output:** (Screenshot)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Get a bit of A4 plain paper,  work away from your computer for ten minutes.

Now, establish what you're trying to achieve in blocks, what do you want each part of your skillset/language/operator-syntax (PHP, javascript, CSS, HTML etc.) to do?

You have a list of outputs already displayed on your project and you want to mark a chosen output, as differet from the others.

work backwards from that end result, what will make this change? That's right, **CSS**, so you can write on your paper, you need a CSS class (or other identifier) for a chosen output, that you can call for that answer.

So how will the CSS know which output to choose? Where is this data held?

This data appears to be in **PHP** somewhere, (but it's not immediately obvious from your code). So, you need a PHP **`IF`** statement to check *If the answer that is being displayed to the browser is the answer that the user has chosen* then that answer needs to be encased in a CSS class somehow (`<div>` or `<span>` ) to effect the dfference in appearance.

And that's it. You should have enough of a structure now to go away and to write out notes on that A4 sheet and then use those notes to break your various issues down into component parts (here, there are parts for *difining* what behaviour should happen and then parts for *making* that behaviour happen).

Rewrite your code in 5-10 minutes you'll have it exactly as you want it.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I'm realizing it's important to step back from my work sometimes in order to think about what I really want to do. This is good advice for anyone tackling a problem.

Comment: @MichalPatriak Glad you got it sorted out, and it is a certain irony that some of the best computer programming is actually laid out and planned and setup with a pen and paper. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there... just make it simple:

If you have:

```
$question =  $_SESSION['question'];
$radio = $_SESSION['radio'];
$answerArray = [$_SESSION['answer0'], $_SESSION['answer1'], $_SESSION['answer2'], $_SESSION['answer3']];
```

Then you can:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['radio'])) {
  foreach ($answerArray as $value) {
    echo $_SESSION['radio'] == $value ? "<span style=\"color:green\">Make $value green.</span><br />" : "<span style=\"color:#666\">Make $value grey or red.</span><br />";
  }
} else {
  echo "Please click the back button in your browser and select a correct answer";
}
```

Which equals to:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['radio'])) {
  foreach ($answerArray as $value) {
    if ($_SESSION['radio'] == $value){
      echo "<span style=\"color:green\">Make $value green.</span><br />";
    } else {
      echo "<span style=\"color:#666\">Make $value grey or red.</span><br />";
    }
  }
} else {
  echo "Please click the back button in your browser and select a correct answer";
}
```